# How to determine motherboard serial number

Tags: motherboard, dell-latitude, serial

I determined that my motherboard is broken. Since I cannot turn on my laptop, how can I see which model of motherboard I have and what its serial number is? I need to buy new one.

My laptop is a Dell Latitude E5530.

What is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: Did you try to google `dell latitude e5530 motherboard` or disassemble the laptop?

Comment: Sure, I found a couple of motherboard but I need S-N for that
But in my laptop I cannot find it

Comment: If you can't boot it then you'll have to disassemble it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for **Dell** make use of the `service tag` and `express service code` which should be stickers on the underside of laptop.  Plug those in at support.dell.com to look up the laptop info/specs/warranty.

I know on Dell stuff, laptops or desktops, you go into bios and what it shows as the *serial number* is the `service tag` number and the service tag is unique for all dell equipment... for example my e5530 laptop has whatever service tag whereas your identical laptop will have a different 5-7 character service tag.

supposedly the express service code is the base-10 representation of the alphanumeric service tag.

Comment: https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/latitude-e5530/overview

Comment: being a laptop and u said *motherboard broken* that is basically the laptop then, and the *best solution* i think might be a new complete laptop.  Unless it's under warranty I don't think *motherboard* is a replaceable part.

Comment: The motherboard is replaceable. I've replaced a few of them through warranty replacements. I've never searched for the motherboard information myself and am having quite a bit of trouble doing so now. The information shown by `wmic baseboard get product, serialnumber, version` as suggested by Dell shows the part number for the lower assembly, but most of the ones I've found on the Dell website don't include the motherboard; just the assembly.

Comment: @ron Yes Ron. I also think that best solution is to buy new one. Since I see price of motherboard is 100-150$, this is just throwing money. 
Thank you for information :)